# Multiple selection Calendar for jsf

Tags: calendar, selection

Is there an already implemented Calendar for JSF which allows the user to select multiple dates? I need a calendar in which I can select more than one date.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with primefaces http://www.primefaces.org:8080/prime-showcase/ui/calendarMultipleSelection.jsf